# Why doesn't comparing var to "text" work?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I made an `if` and `else` statement in Javascript, but I can't get it to work. 

This is my code, I hope you people will see whats wrong

```
var int = "";
function fbLoop (userLoop)
{
    int=setInterval(function(){fbCheckloop(userLoop)},1000);
}

function fbCheckloop(userCheck)
{
    if(userCheck.login != 'false')
    {
        window.clearInterval(int);
        console.log(userCheck);
        fbUpload(userCheck);
    }
    else
    {
        $.get("uploadtofb.php", {functie: "checklogin", fotonaam: userCheck.fotonaam}, fbCheckloop);
    }
}
```

The `if(userCheck.login != 'false')` doesn't work. 
The `console.log(userCheck);` shows this
`{"login":"false","fotonaam":"NAME"}`
So according to the console log he have to do the `else`, but he does the `if` statement.

What did I do wrong?

The `userCheck` is coming from this:
`return json_encode($checklog = array(
                'login' => 'false',
                'fotonaam' => $_GET['fotonaam']
        ));`

Comment: Please show where `userCheck` comes from.

Comment: Please, trace by console.log this value `userCheck.login`, not a whole `userCheck` object

Comment: @EminA.Alekperov That gives me this `undefined`.

Comment: @Michelenzoo: This too suggests that `userCheck` is a string and not an object. A string does not have a `login` property, but your object would have. (Given the console log you've provided, otherwise it could be any object, that just doesn't have that property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that `userCheck` is a JavaScript object, and not a JSON string that has to be parsed? Your current console log result makes me suspect that it is. What does `console.log(typeof userCheck)` yield?

If it is, use

```
userCheck = JSON.parse(userCheck)
```

Comment: In the userCheck is the information from an JSON array.
I will try, and let you know.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Your answer helped me out! Many thanks for the fast help guys!

Answer (score 0):

if `userCheck.login` is having boolean value `false`, use `if(userCheck.login != false)`.

No quotes required around `false`.

Comment: Even when it's like this in the userCheck.login:
'login' => 'false' ?
Many thanks for your answer!